# Make an object that can be compared and hashed with variable attributes, in Python

Tags: class, oop, python-3.x, text-processing

I am working on a package that deals with citations and most of them are of the form

```
Author, Year, Journal, Volume, Page, DOI
```

So a a string with series of fields separated by commas.Unfortunately some (~5%) are missing one (or often more than one) of these fields.

To do useful things with them I need to be able to check if two are the same ignoring a field if it is missing. I have an `__eq__(self, other)` defined that does this with a series of if statements like this:

```
elif hasattr(self, 'V') and hasattr(other, 'V') and getattr(self, 'V') != getattr(other, 'V'):
        return False
```

The one constant about the citations is that author is present and at least one of year or journal is too.

I feel like there should be a much faster way of doing this, but have not been able to come up with one. Is there a faster way of doing this as that would really help with processing?

Comment: Do you want to citations that differ only in that one field is present in one but missing in the other to compare equal? E.g. `author, year, page` versus `author, year`? If so, your current code won't do it (it only compare two citations equal if they both have or don't have each attribute).

Comment: @Blckknght Sorry for the confusion I actually want both behaviours, but the one I just added is is the more difficult one that I want help with.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a long `if`/`elif` chain and explicitly returning `Fase` if a condition finds a mismatch, you can chain together the comparisons directly in a Boolean expression with `and`:

```
return (self.author == other.author and
        self.year == other.year and
        self.journal == other.journal
        ...)
```

You can keep using your `getattr` calls if you want, but I'd suggest moving the logic to fill in `None` for missing values into the initialization code, rather than needing to repeat it anywhere you check the attributes. That way you'll always have the attributes you expect, ones that don't have meaningful data will simply have `None` as their value.

Note that the current behavior of your `getattr` code doesn't quite match the description you give of your desired behavior ("check if two are the same ignoring a field if it is missing"). The current code will return `False` if an attribute is present in one citation and not in another, even if the rest of the values match up. If you want the behavior to match your description, use something like this:

```
not (hasattr(self, "year") and (hasattr(other, "year")) or self.year == other.year
```

Or (if you do `year = None` in `__init__` if there's no year specified):

```
None in (self.year, other.year) or self.year == other.year
```

Comment: You are right about the the behaviour I have changed my post to match, Years are a special case which I forgot when I copied it over, sorry for the lack of clarity.